# Did Vladimir Putin state that Trump is a puppet?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, russian-federation, vladimir-putin

Weeks ago I read in an opinion news paper article whose author said that Vladimir Putin thought that all the USA presidents he had met were just "mere puppets".

There is also a [video interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xykvrGpCW6E) in which Putin said that some elements in government tell all the administrations how things are done. In that interview, Putin goes on to illustrate his point with Obama's sincere but ultimately ineffective attempt at closing down Guantanamo. The subheading added by Russia Insight was

> Putin Tells It Like It Is: US Presidents Are Puppets, 'Men in Dark Suits' Rule Washington

So, is there any video, article, interview etc. in which Putin made that "puppet" statement (or similar) one referring to Trump?

Comment: I've actually been bold and made some edits along the line I mentioned. I would be even better if you could find & link the opinion piece that has the "mere puppets" statement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's hard to prove a negative, but given that Putin is trying to mend relations with US/Trump, I strongly doubt he would have said something that scathing (i.e. directly call Trump a puppet) in public. The 2017 video/interview you've linked to--in which Putin's example is Obama's troubles in closing Guantanamo--was further editorialized in its subheading (by Russia Insight) to add the "puppet" claim. Putin didn't even say that explicitly about Obama, with whom he doesn't have any more horses to trade. So it's doubly doubtful Putin would directly attack Trump with an ad hominem like that.

Comment: Agreed that Putin would not say that publicly. FWIW, [ https://www.vox.com/conversations/2017/2/22/14697718/trump-putin-helsinki-meeting-hillary-clinton], the editor of the Moscow Times makes clear his thoughts on the Putin-Trump relationship.